# Why can this not be done?

Tags: java

I want to shorten my code using a loop. I have for example 5 zombies in my game. So I thought I could do this

```
Image zombie;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
if (zombie.getZombieRect().intersects(zombie + i + .getZombieRect())) {
}}
```

Why can this not be done? adding i to the end of zombie. zombie being an image. The oother variables are zombie1, zombie2 etc.
Thanks for all help.

Comment: Not sure what types and operations are allowed on `zombie`. Please post all code/

Comment: You need them to be in an array and consume from it: `zombie[i]`. You can't dynamically get the variables by their name.

Comment: @hexafraction looks like OP wants/needs to use something like `zombie1`, `zombie2`, `zombie3`...

Comment: Yeesh, that's a mess.  As @LuiggiMendoza says, you need to iterate over a collection.

Answer (score 8):

This is what arrays are for:

```
Zombie zombies[] = {zombie, zombie1, zombie2, zombie3, zombie4};
for (int i = 0; i < zombies.length; i++) {
    if (zombie.getZombieRect().intersects(zombies[i].getZombieRect())) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you can replace `i < 5` by `i < zombies.length`

Comment: & you can simply it further with `for (Image zombie: zombies){…}`. Just to note that the OP is comparing `zombie` to `zombieN` so the one without the number should live outside the array.

Answer (score 1):

Make an Array of Objects and then u can call them by using zombie[i] etc whatever you want to do.
The thing of adding you are trying to do is suitable in case of strings only
       "zombie"+i;
etc.

Comment: It is suitable only in the case of printing strings, and even then you are merely concatenating a string with an int which obviously is possible. You cant dynamically create a variable name for string objects

Comment: What do you want to say?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question,

```
zombie + i
```

Is a compile-time error because java does not allow an Image object to be used in combination with an int in the '+' operator.